# Visualforce page with Standard Page Layout on New Record

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I've turned the interweb upside down looking for an answer to this issue with no luck.

**Use Case**

We are developing a Managed Package app
Users are high-frequency data entry operators
Users don't want to enter a value in the Name field on most Objects
We cannot use AutoNumber for Name field because they mean nothing to end-users

We created a simple extension class that takes a value from a Custom Setting and populates that into the Name field when creating new records

We also have simple VF pages for each object that were returning the Standard native page layout nicely AND populating the Name field =  SWEET result

We also used this so users could use our app via the nice SF1 native UI when creating new records without seeing the 'dated' look and feel of VF pages if you hard-code all fields

Here is what we used in our VF pages and it worked nicely for a long time and it showed the native page layout in both the desktop and SF1 app and it didn't require us to spend days and weeks coding VF pages with inputfields, etc for over 140 custom objects. Just edit the Standard page Layout and i was reflected in the VF page version

**VF page - Calendar Days**

```
      <apex:page standardController="Calendar_Day__c" extensions="DefaultName" standardStylesheets="true" tabStyle="Calendar_Day__c" showHeader="true" docType="html-5.0"  title="Calendar Days">
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**

```
        public with sharing class DefaultName {
        public SObject obj;
        public ApexPages.StandardController stdCon;
        public DefaultName__c mc;

     public DefaultName(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
      {
      obj = (SObject)stdCon.getRecord();  
      if((obj.get('Name')== '' ||obj.get('Name')== null) ||  obj.get('Name').equals('System-generated ID Field'))
     { 
      obj.put('Name', mc.Name_CS__c);
    else
     {
      obj.put('Name', obj.get('Name'));
     }
  } 
}
```

However, recently it has completely stopped working and each VF page is now completely blank (bar the header and sidebar) in Desktop and SF1.

If I replace the extensions="DefaultName" attribute to {!URLFOR($Action.Calendar__c.New, null, ['Name'='Leave Blank'], true)}, it works as expected in the Desktop and renders nicely in SF1.

**Assumptions**
-Enable for Mobile is on for each VF page (tested with it off and no difference)

-We are logged in using a custom Systems Administrator Profile and Role.

-Admittedly, we have been building out the Security Model a lot lately, but this was our first port of call and all seems good....apex classes are on the profile, vf pages are on the profile, View All and modify All are on, objects are all read/write, systems permissions are sweet

-We reviewed about 40 VF pages and the same thing is happening on ALL of them...

**Conclusion**
We are completely stumped why it is not rendering any of the standard page layouts now and desperately need some guidance on what to look at next please?

Also, I am worried this will cause us grief when we do our Security Review for Managed Package status and whether it is best practice? Is this unfounded or a real concern?

Cheers for any guidance or assistance anyone can send our way. This is crippling us.

Comment: Addendum: Apologies for the poor formatting of the apex class and the VF page code has disappeared so here it is again 

'<apex:page standardController="Calendar_Day__c" extensions="DefaultName" standardStylesheets="true" tabStyle="Calendar_Day__c" showHeader="true" docType="html-5.0"  title="Calendar Days">

</apex:page>'

Comment: You need to prefix your code with four spaces. You can highlight the code and Ctrl+K to do this automatically.

Comment: I don't see anything on your page that would display anything or anything in the controller that would redirect to the standard page with the name populated. Am I missing something or did you just leave markup out?

Comment: @Eric, We haven't needed to do anything other than what is currently shown in the VF page code listed above......hence the reason why there is no markup...that was the beauty of it...thanks for trying...looks like we are going to have to take the long road after all and code it all manually....

Comment: I agree with @Eric - if this did used to display the original full edit page on what is an "empty" visualforce page, even I had no idea this happened/existed! What you are trying to achieve (to me) is a long standing problem in SFDC that there is no "manageable" apex:detail tag for edit.

Comment: Update: Turns out one of our junior devs had removed the  <apex:detail/> tag that was previously rendering the existing page layouts....